# Trying to prove pre image of product of ideals is, the product of the pre images of the two ideals...

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

This is from Elements of Abstract Algebra by Allan Clark. 166 $\beta$

$\Phi ^{-1}(a'b') = (\phi^{-1}(a'))(\phi^{-1}(b'))$

I can prove an element of the right side is an element of the left. But I can't prove an element of the left is an element of the right. $\phi$ is a ring epimorphism from R to R'. a' and b' are ideals of R'.

Would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Is my edit okay?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much. I'm new to MathJax. Your edit is perfect.

Comment: I think I found a way to solve this. But I used the idea of a quotient ring which was only defined in the textbook after this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated, the claim is actually false. The problem is that the right hand side is a product of ideals, whereas the left hand side need not be. If $b' = 0$, then writing $K = \ker \phi$, the claim becomes $K = \phi^{-1}(a')K$, which is not true if $R$ is Noetherian local (unless $a'$ is the unit ideal or $K = 0$, by Nakayama's lemma). Even if one requires that both $a', b'$ are nonzero, the claim still need not be true, as in the following example:

Let $R = k[x,y]/(y^2)$, $S = k[y]/(y^2)$ ($k$ is a field), and $\phi : R \twoheadrightarrow S$ given by $x \mapsto 0$, $y \mapsto y$ (i.e. quotient $R$ by $(x)$). Take $a' = b' = (y)S$. Then $\phi^{-1}(a') = \phi^{-1}(b') = (x,y)R$, and their product is $(\phi^{-1}(a'))(\phi^{-1}(b')) = (x,y)^2 = (xy,x^2)$, but $\phi^{-1}(a'b') = \phi^{-1}(0) = (x)R$, which is strictly larger.

Comment: Thanks! The b'=0 substitution made it clear that the claim is false.