# Inverse image of anhilator ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $f$ be a ring homomorphism from $R\rightarrow S$ and $J$ be annihilator of some ideal in $S$. Under what conditions on $R$ and kernel of $f$ , $f^{-1} (J) $ is annihilator of some ideal of $R$.

This question seems hard to me although its elementary and it gives me hard time in solving this. I think if kernel of $f$ is annihilator of some ideal in $R$ then it comes. But I still in process of proving that. Is there any sufficient/nesscasry conditions for this.

Comment: If $s\in f^{-1}(S)$ (this is an idea because the inverse image of an ideal is an ideal) and $j\in f^{-1}(J)$, then $f(js)=f(j)f(s)=0$, so a necessary condition would be that the kernel of $f$ intersects $JS$ trivially (for instance if $f$ is injective).

Comment: It is also sufficient because if $a$ is in the annihilator of $f^{-1}(S)$, then then $f(a)$ is in the annihilator of $S$, and therefore $a\in f^{-1}(J)$.

Comment: Sorry, I used the letter $S$ for the ideal, let me write an answer with proper notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism and $I$ an ideal of $S$ with annihilator $J$. Then $f^{-1}(I)$ [is an ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693618/prove-the-pre-image-of-an-ideal-is-an-ideal). If $j\in f^{-1}(J)$ and $a\in f^{-1}(I)$, then $f(ja)=f(j)f(a)=0$. So for $j$ to annihilate every element of $f^{-1}(I)$ it is necessary that the kernel of $f$ intersects $jf^{-1}(I)$ trivially. Therefore, for $f^{-1}(J)$ to annihilate $f^{-1}(I)$ we need that the kernel of $f$ intersects $f^{-1}(J)f^{-1}(I)$ trivially (watch out because [this is not $f^{-1}(IJ)$ in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664384/trying-to-prove-pre-image-of-product-of-ideals-is-the-product-of-the-pre-images)).

This condition is also sufficient because if $r\in R$ annihilates $f^{-1}(I)$, then $f(r)$ annihilates $I$, so $f(r)\in J$, meaning that $r\in f^{-1}(J)$.

Comment: I was close but I was looking at sufficient conditions so I failed to see $ja$ is necessarily identity